I need to redirect to an HTTP endpoint to show a common error message if any action fails. in power automat

My flow can fail at various points, and identifying the origin of the issue can be challenging. To address this, I want to redirect users to a specific HTTP endpoint that displays a common error message whenever a failure occurs. This way, I can ensure that users are informed of the error, even if I don't have immediate details on where or why the issue happened.
I’m seeking suggestions on the best practices for implementing this error handling mechanism. What are the most efficient ways to set up this redirect, and how can I ensure that the error message is clear and helpful for troubleshooting? Any advice on tools, frameworks, or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

i have get solution. i have use scope action scope action is one type of try & catch, if you test any actions add in try and you show any common error message so add http or any other action you requirment wise after check.
if your flow is faild any actions so return in catch action.
i give example image.
click here
